# Text rotatator flickering at the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a text rotator that uses speed and interval to determine how fast and when to rotate the text. Everything seems to be working ok, just the only issue I have is the flickering between the last and the first transitions. So in other words I can see the old and the new entry together. Can someone help me to avoid this?
My [JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6yrzsvr/)

And my JQuery code is:

```
    (function($) {


  $(document).ready(function(){

    //<![CDATA[

    (function($) {
      $.fn.rotator = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
          interval: 5000,
          speed:800,
        }, settings);

        return this.each(function() {
          var $t = $(this),
              $item = $t.children().addClass('item').hide();

          $t.addClass('rotator');

          if ($item.length > 1) {
            $item.first().addClass('current').fadeIn(settings.speed);
            setInterval(function() {
              var c = $t.find('.current');
              if (c.next().length === 0) {
                c.removeClass('current').fadeOut(settings.speed);
                $item.first().addClass('current').fadeIn(settings.speed);
              } else {
                c.fadeOut(settings.speed, function () {
                  $(this).removeClass('current')
                    .next().addClass('current')
                    .fadeIn(settings.speed)
                });
              }
            }, settings.interval);
          }
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    // Execute here!
    $(function() {
      $('#slider').rotator();
    });
    //]]>



  });


})(jQuery);
```